# Adding column value dynamically in select statement SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have 2 SQL tables like below

**Table1**

```
ServerName  Downloaded  Failed RebootRequried
server1     3            2      Yes
Server2     4            1      NO
```

**Table2**

```
ServerName    Administartor
server1       John
server3       Alex
```

I want to join these 2 tables so that I can extract the administrator name out of Table 2.

If the serverName of Table 1 is not matching with serverName of Table2 , then I want to retain all the columns `ServerName,Downloaded,Failed, RebootRequired, Administrator(Which will be null)`.

If ServerName matches then all the columns should be retained including administrator name from Table2?

How can we do it with select statement in sql? I am pretty new to it ,and not sure how to use the conditional statement in sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `left join`. join `tables1` and `table2`  on `servername`.

for more insight go through tutorials about [joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT 
ServerName,
Downloaded,
Failed, 
RebootRequired, 
Administrator
FROM 
Table1 t1 
left join Table2 t2 
on 
t1.ServerName=t2.ServerName
```